# unable to associate app with windows store for push notification

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2017, windows-store, wns

in order to enable and test `windows notification service (WNS)` over `UWP - windows 10`

i have a associate developer account in windows store but when i am trying to choose option by right clicking on windows project and selecting

> Store -> Associate App with the Store -> Next

i am getting following error

[image]

Not sure why i am getting this error , i try searching different threads over web but could not find the solution. As the error says i need to enable the permission but don't know how can i enable the permission from window store dashboard.

in account settings my basic account details are as follows and i am using `Visual Studio Enterprise Edition 2017`

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to repro the same error by testing our company account with VS Enterprise 2017. Do you sign in VS with the original account registered by you? And also, if possible, you could try it with other version VS to confirm if the issue indeed results from your account. If so, you could open up a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your account to let Dev Center support review your specific case.

Comment: i am using the same credentials in VS 2017 and even while associating app. i tried with VS2015 but result is same. have open up the support ticket lets see

Comment: Any update? Have you known the reason for your app being blocked by Store?

Comment: They are escalating the issue , we have tried with manager's permission and customer permissions too but still no luck. but its disappointing as its killing our development time